# Saving png image to the database

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I am trying to save a `.png` image to the database. I have a column in database table called `sign` of type `varbinary(max)` and I have following in the model class:

```
public partial class EmployeeInfo
{
    public int EmployeeInfoId { get; set; }
    public byte[]? Sign { get; set; }
}
```

This is my view:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col">
        <canvas width="500" height="400" id="signature"
                style="border:1px solid black"></canvas>
        <br>
        <button type="button" id="accept"
                class="btn btn-primary">
             Accept signature
        </button>
        <br>
    </div>
    <br />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="SignatureDataUrl">
</div>
```

`SignaturedataURL` is already getting saved in the database as you can see:

[image]

I want to save a `.png` image to the database. I have the following code in my controller:

```
string path = Path.GetTempPath();

if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(employeeInfo.SignatureDataUrl))
{
    var base64Signature = employeeInfo.SignatureDataUrl.Split(",")[1];
    var binarySignature = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Signature);

    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@path + "\\Signature.png", binarySignature);
}
```

Instead of saving `Signature.png` to this path, I want to save `signature.png` to the database column `Sign`. How can I do that?

Comment: Did you get any error here? Actually the `binarySignature` you get is the correct value for the byte[] Sign here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Sign` is a byte array, if you want to store it in database, the `binarySignature` you get is the correct value.

```
var base64Signature = SignatureDataUrl.Split(",")[1]; //split the image url and get the base64string
var binarySignature = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Signature);//convert base64string to byte[]
//add the following code....
employeeInfo.Sign = binarySignature;
_dbContext.EmployeeInfo.Add(employeeInfo);
_dbContext.SaveChanges();   //save the entity to table in database
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@path + "\\Signature.png", binarySignature); //save the file to the path
```

Comment: Do I need to save the file to the path or saving the binarySignature is enough? What I need to do is retrieve the signature later and put the signature in an image box inside a pdf file. I can easily put the signature inside the image box. The problem is should I put the .png file inside image box or binary signature is enough

Comment: Hi @Anjali, if you just want to display the image stored in the database, save the path or binary is enough. If the image has been uploaded to the server, you can just store one of the file path and binary. If it is not uploaded to the server, you must store the binary.

Comment: Hi @Rena, I can store the image when I draw something on Canvas, but writing something on the canvas using the keyboard is not working. Its a simple JQuery issue. I cannot figure out why writng something on the canvas is not working.